# Карта товара ссылкой

Tags: drupal

Помогите, пожалуйста, сделать карту товара ссылкой.

В `views` я вывел несколько полей. Все поля, кроме последнего исключил из вывода. И в последнем при помощи токенов вывел все поля. Далее мне нужно все эти поля обернуть в ссылку, которая будет вести на материал. Но проблема в том, что карта товара имеет форму с кнопкой "в корзину". То есть эта форма не может быть внутри ссылки, а значит я не могу использовать стандартную опцию "вывести ссылкой"

Код примерно такой:

[image: код]

Здесь ссылка это .`link_to_node`
А блок `.buy_area` я не хотел бы помещать в ссылку так ка в нём форма

Вот так внешне выглядит карта товара:

[image: карта товара]

Если интересно, я пытался все поля скрыть и вывести после них 2 поля. В одном вывел поля, которые должны быть в ссылке, в другом - форму с кнопкой "в корзину". Далее я попытался для первого поля включить опцию "вывести ссылкой" и в путь прописать токен [view_node]. В результате получил примерно такой путь